# Adding custom post types to archive

Tags: custom-post-types

I am wanting to dispaly custom post types on my archive pages using code from here:

```
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179023/adding-custom-post-types-to-archive-php
```

but this now gives WP error message of:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php on line 613

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');

function query_post_type($query) {
  if($query->is_main_query()
    && ( is_category() || is_tag() )) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post','cpt') );
  }
}
```

Please let me know what changes are needed to not return errors.

Comment: what are the names of your custom post types? are you trying to include more than one custom post type into the archive?

Comment: No, I just want to show 1 cpt in the archive. The specific name is "asana" and if I change this nothing shows in the archive.

Comment: You shouldn't need any code. As long as `has_archive` is true when registering the post type you will get an archive automatically at `/asana/`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related to how you register the custom post type.

Did you add the "taxonomies" argument in the register_post_type? If yes, is it a string? Try to convert it in an array of strings.

See the the example below...

```
    register_post_type(
        'custom_post_type_slug',
        array(
            'labels'               => array ( /* ... */ ),
            'public'               => true,
            /* ... */
            'taxonomies'           => array( 'custom_post_taxonomy_slug' ),
        )
    );
```